# vim tabe split open more than 10 files from command line

Tags: vim, command

I want to open multiple .cpp .h files in pair with `tabe` and `sp` commands. Suppose the current workplace has a.h, a.cpp, b.h, b.cpp, ... z.h, z.cpp.

I tried the following:

```
vim a.cpp -c 'sp a.h' -c 'tabe b.cpp' -c 'sp b.h' -c 'tabe c.cpp' -c 'sp c.h' -c 'tabe d.cpp' -c 'sp d.h' -c 'tabe e.cpp' -c 'sp e.h' -c 'tabe f.cpp'
```

which will work. However, the number of `-c` commands is limited to 10. 
So if want open more than 12 files, it will fail.

```
vim a.cpp -c 'sp a.h' -c 'tabe b.cpp' -c 'sp b.h' -c 'tabe c.cpp' -c 'sp c.h' -c 'tabe d.cpp' -c 'sp d.h' -c 'tabe e.cpp' -c 'sp e.h' -c 'tabe f.cpp' -c 'sp f.h' ...
```

will fail.

Is there a way to make this work?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `|` to separate command in vim. So you can combine all of your `-c` into one command and pass that to `-c`

```
vim a.cpp -c 'sp a.h | tabe b.cpp | sp b.h | tabe c.cpp | ...'
```

---

Assuming you were in a folder with all the cpp and header files you could just run

```
vim -p *.cpp -c 'tabdo sp %<.h'
```

to simply everything. `-p` tells vim to open all the files in tabs. So for every cpp file in the directory you will have one tab. After vim is loaded it will then run `sp %<.h` in each of the tabs. Where
`%<.h` is the original filename with the extension change to `.h`. (`%<` is the filename without extension. Take a look at `:help %<`)

---

Vim defaults to only having 10 tab pages. If you need to open more than that you need to increase the `tabpagemax` value.

```
set tabpagemax=100
```

Take a look at `:help tabpagemax` (If you need this many tab pages I would recommend learning how to use buffers)

Comment: Thanks. it works:) And I am try to write a shell script, which can open all .h .cpp files in pair in a specific folder. Is there a vim command to do that? Tried -o -p. Thanks.

Comment: @chris I would probably just do `vim -p *.cpp -c 'tabdo sp %<.h'`